# About normalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $$f\colon X \to Y$$ be a morphism of affine normal algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $f$ is birational and bijective on closed points. Does normality imply that $f$ is an isomorphism? Does it follow from Stein's factorization?

(I am especially interested in the surface case, but I do not see why this should help.)

Comment: There is also the related notion of *seminormality*.  $Y$ (a variety over $\mathbb{C}$) is called seminormal if every map of varieties $X \to Y$ which is finite and bijective is an isomorphism (and hence birational as well).  Normal implies seminormal.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference about semi-normality? Or criteria to test it? I have never come across it.

Comment: I think probably googling it will give you some references.  The classic reference is Greco-Traverso.  There was a recent survey (from an algebraic perspective) by Marie Vitulli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please confer Zariski's Main Theorem, pp. 288-289 of Mumford's "Red Book of Varieties and Schemes".  Using the "original form", $f$ is an open immersion.  Using the hypothesis about bijectivity on closed points, $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In Section III.9 Page 209 Second Edition he addresses explicitly my question.